# MongoDB (mongoose) - group on categoris and subcategories in document

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I have a mongo collection of documents having category, subcategory and item names.
Category is an enum ["A", "B", "C"], subCategory and item are Strings.

```
{ _id: 1, category: "A", subCategory: "a1", item: "item1"}
{ _id: 2, category: "A", subCategory: "a1", item: "item2"}
{ _id: 3, category: "A", subCategory: "a1", item: "item3"}
{ _id: 4, category: "A", subCategory: "a2", item: "item4"}
{ _id: 5, category: "B", subCategory: "b1", item: "item5"}
{ _id: 6, category: "B", subCategory: "b1", item: "item6"}
```

I am trying to write a query which will return the data in the following format:

```
{
   A: [
       { subCategory: 'a1', items: ["item1", "item2", "item3"]},
       { subCategory: 'a2', items: ["item4",]}
   ],
   B: [
       { subCategory: 'b1', items: ["item5", "item6"]}
   ]
}
```

Here is what I have tried so far:

```
const items = await Items.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: { category: "$category", subCategory: "$subCategory" },
      items: { $push: "$item" },
    },
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id.category",
      subCategories: {
        $push: {
          subCategory: "$_id.subCategory",
          items: "$items",
        },
      },
    },
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      category: "$_id",
      subCategories: 1,
    },
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      array: [
        {
          k: "$category",
          v: "$subCategories",
        },
      ],
    },
  },
  {
    $replaceRoot: {
      newRoot: { $arrayToObject: "$array" },
    },
  },
]);
```

And here is the output (close, but not exactly what I need):

```
[
    {
        A: [
            { subCategory: 'a1', items: ["item1", "item2", "item3"]},
            { subCategory: 'a2', items: ["item4",]}
        ],
    },
    {
        B: [
            { subCategory: 'b1', items: ["item5", "item6"]}
        ]
    },
]
```

Please advise, how can I achieve the required result

Comment: Your desired format will end up in a single large object. Although this is possible, I would highly recommend against doing it at the database layer. Databases are supposed to work with records. You can handle the transformation at your application layer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below aggregation query :

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    /** Group on `category + subCategory` & push item's to `items` array */
    {
      $group: { _id: { category: "$category", subCategory: "$subCategory" }, items: { $push: "$item" } }
    },
    /** Group on `category` field & push objects({subCategory:...,items:...}) to `v` field */
    {
      $group: { _id: "$_id.category", v: { $push: { subCategory: "$_id.subCategory", items: "$items" } } }
    },
    /** remove `_id` field & add `k` field & project `v` field */
    {
      $project: { _id: 0, k: "$_id", v: 1 }
    },
    /** Replace root doc with arrayToObject convert root doc */
    {
      $replaceRoot: { newRoot: { $arrayToObject: [ [ "$$ROOT" ] ] } }
    },
    /** Group on empty will just group on all docs without a filter & merge all objects  */
    {
      $group: { _id: "", data: { $mergeObjects: "$$ROOT" } }
    },
    { 
        $replaceRoot: { newRoot: "$data" }
    }
  ])
```

**Test :** [mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/8b6hrp6GQ-G)

**Ref :** [aggregation-pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-pipeline/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it still not exactly what I am trying to achieve. This query returns array with object inside, like this [{A:[],B:[]}]. How can I "extract" the object from array, so the query will return object like this {A:[],B:[]}

Comment: It is not missing anything. Array with an object inside is returned, instead of just an object

Comment: @shulyaev : not matter what happens `aggregation` will always return an array : 1) Empty array `[]` if not  matching docs found, 2) An array with one or many objects/docs `[{}]` or `[{},{}]` in the response, So common thing is : Output of aggregation is an array ! As this query will get you only one object in array - In your code you can just do `result[0]` to get first object from array - which is what you're looking for !!